# Are there any contemporary dictionaries for people with learning differences?

Tags: grammar

That someone like me who has dyslexia could use?

I want a dictionary which not only has plenty examples but also the definition itself is in contemporary language.

And by contemporary I mean spoken English.

Preferably offline. Paid would also do.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the learning disorder.  If you mean "dyslexia" (not actually a learning disorder - it's a learning difficulty, because it doesn't affect intellect), there are plenty for children who are native speakers.  If you mean something like Downs syndrome, that would depend on how much your intellectual ability is affected. I don't think an answer is possible without more detail on what you mean.

Comment: However all contemporary dictionaries use contemporary language for the definition.

Comment: I think I only have dyslexia. Thank you

Comment: I'm VTCing as 'Blatantly off-topic" because there is no better alternative, but per the [Help] guidelines, "requests for resources" are off-topic, and we have a better site for that anyway: [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps a moderator can migrate the question?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a *learner's* dictionary.  There are plenty of these available, both online and on paper, google "[Learner's dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=learner%27s%20dictionary)". Oxford, Cambridge, MW, Collins - all have learner's dictionaries. They are typically aimed at a B1-C1 level of English. Below that level, bilingual dictionaries and target vocabulary lists are generally more useful.

Dictionaries for dyslexic people also exist, but they serve a different function. People with dyslexia have difficulty spelling, but no difficulty with the meaning of words.  A dictionary for dyslexic children will include the words with difficult spelling and no definitions, or only short definitions, without examples.  A native speaker with dyslexia doesn't want lots of examples since that means lots of reading.

Dictionaries also exist for people with learning disorders.  They may be more like glossaries of words to help people cope with a particular situation such as "applying for benefits".